# How to make Drag and Drop of nodes work inside a Radial Reingold–Tilford Tree in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am implementing a Radial Reingold–Tilford Tree (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) but along with the basic example with that pan and zoom, drag and also collapsible clickable node.
I have been able to implement most of it. However one more thing I need is drag and drop of different node to other node. I have been able to implement that too, but while dragging I want to show the link/temporary connector too but it is becoming a hassle to implement at a radial view.

I am at a loss at what to do after this. 
This is my present working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/rabimba/d6DVn/1/

The portion I need to first calculate it correctly while the draglistener should be

```
                relCoords = d3.mouse($('svg').get(0));
            if (relCoords[0] < panBoundary) {
                panTimer = true;
                pan(this, 'left');
            } else if (relCoords[0] > ($('svg').width() - panBoundary)) {

                panTimer = true;
                pan(this, 'right');
            } else if (relCoords[1] < panBoundary) {
                panTimer = true;
                pan(this, 'up');
            } else if (relCoords[1] > ($('svg').height() - panBoundary)) {
                panTimer = true;
                pan(this, 'down');
            } else {
                try {
                    clearTimeout(panTimer);
                } catch (e) {

                }
            }

            d.x0 += d3.event.dy;
            d.y0 += d3.event.dx;
            var node = d3.select(this);
            node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.y0 + "," + (d.x - 90 )+ ")");
            updateTempConnector();
        })
```

Then I can start working on the connectors.
I have commented as much as possible.

Comment: In your fiddle we are getting an error,
dofocus is not defined check it once.Okay

Comment: Yup. That is okay. That portion of the code is not needed here. That is for my internal operations for the json, which for the fiddle I just hardcoded. You can safely ignore that

Comment: Hi @RabimbaKaranjai Since this example is taken from my code http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree/ I can sefly say that you shouldn't worry about the panning in th above snippet just yet. The panning seems to work fine in anycase, however the location of the dragged node is wrong along with `tempConnector`

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem is the way the nodes have their `x` and `y` values set.  Their actual positions are dictated by the `transform` function

.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";

Which means that the actual `x` and `y` coordinates in the svg canvas are a function of an angle `d.x-90` and their depth `y`.  This means that the `updateTempConnector` isn't getting the true `x` `y` coordinates to make the line look connected to the `mouseOver` node.
I suggest you look into either the complex trigonometry required to get the actual coordinates or fiddle around with the fiddle below where I have managed to make some limited progress!

Particularly by using these values as the source for the tempLink gotten from the `this` reference in `overCircle`

```
source: {
                x:  (selectedNode.position.left  - ($('svg g').first().offset().left) - ($('svg g')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width/2)) + radius,
                y: (selectedNode.position.top  - ($('svg g').first().offset().top) - ($('svg g')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height/2)) + radius
            }
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/GFe96/3/

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I was just going through the email. I see the the node drag is now working. I was probing about an alternate route to make it work, thanks to your update I'll probably manage to it do it. I'll keep updating here